# Use WordPress search in external static website

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a static website for my main WordPress website.

I'm trying to add the WordPress search form in my static page so I can still use the search form from my static website.

Here's what I have now:

```
<form action="http://www.domain.com/" method="get">
   <input type="search" name="s" value="" placeholder="type keyword(s) here" />
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What's your question? What's happening/not happening?

Comment: The question is how can I use this WordPress search form in an external static website. I don't need to display the search results in the external website I just need to have the WP Search Form functional inside the external static website is that posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to query the Wordpress site from your form using the [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/).